# Using pandas and other libraries with Java's ScriptEngine

Tags: java, python, java-scripting-engine

I'm running Python through Java's Scripting Engine. The basic hello world is working well, but it fails when I import pandas in the python script.

```
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    ScriptContext scriptContext = new SimpleScriptContext();
    scriptContext.setWriter(stringWriter);
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();

    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
```

ImportError: No module named pandas

Is there a way to install it for Scripting Engine?

I have pandas on my machine installed through command line but that's not the python being used here.

Comment: perhaps you need to run on cmd line:
pip install pandas

Comment: Its already installed through cmd line and is working outside.

Comment: uh okay, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235286/call-python-code-from-java-by-passing-parameters-and-results might help

Comment: I've followed the same approach. Pandas doesn't work for it.

Comment: maybe,  we can find the path of python.exe that java is using, by letting the engine print:
import sys
print(sys.executable)

Comment: Prints "None" for sys.executable

Comment: 'hope someone else would give some ideas :) i wonder what the following would tell us about whether pandas is actually loaded but not accessible and show the path to pandas ... please try via ScriptEngine: 

import sys
import pandas
print(sys.modules['pandas'])