# Run Python with imports via java ScriptEngineManager

Tags: python, java, integration, scriptengine

Similar question have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63657868/using-pandas-and-other-libraries-with-javas-scriptengine) an year ago but no answer yet.

Im running a `Python` script via `Java` and I'm getting

```
ImportError: No module named numpy in <script> at line number 1
```

This is my code:

```java
    public void runScript(String filePath) throws Exception {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

        context.setWriter(writer);
        Options.importSite = false;

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
        engine.eval(new FileReader(filePath), context);
        System.out.println(writer);
    }
```

How do I run script with it's imports?

Of course all the required installations have been installed (with pip install) and that the code runs perfectly when I run it not through java.